# Creating a Menu in Android Activity - WindowManager$BadTokenException

Tags: android

I have an activity that shows the option menu. The only option I have currently is "stop". The goal is to stop a service that is running when "stop" is selected.

Here is my code:

```
public class MenuActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        openOptionsMenu();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.stop, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection.
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.stop:
                stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onOptionsMenuClosed(Menu menu) {
        // Nothing else to do, closing the Activity.
        finish();
    }

}
```

When I run this, I see that first "onCreate: is called, then "onResume" is called, then "onCreateOptionsMenu" is called. But after this I am getting this error:

```
W/WindowManager(  439): Failed looking up window
W/WindowManager(  439): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window null does not exist
W/WindowManager(  439):   at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8108)
W/WindowManager(  439):   at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.addWindow(WindowManagerService.java:2150)
W/WindowManager(  439):   at com.android.server.wm.Session.addToDisplay(Session.java:160)
W/WindowManager(  439):   at android.view.IWindowSession$Stub.onTransact(IWindowSession.java:111)
W/WindowManager(  439):   at com.android.server.wm.Session.onTransact(Session.java:123)
W/WindowManager(  439):   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:351)
W/WindowManager(  439):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
D/AndroidRuntime( 3109): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm( 3109): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2b590930)
W/WindowManager(  439): Attempted to add window with token that is not a window: null.  Aborting.
E/AndroidRuntime( 3109): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 3109): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.google.glass.myapp/com.google.glass.myapp.MenuActivity}: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
E/AndroidRuntime( 3109):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2742)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3109):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2771)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3109):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2235)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3109):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3109):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3109):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3109):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3109):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3109):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3109):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3109):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3109):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3109):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3109): Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
E/AndroidRuntime( 3109):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:590)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3109):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:246)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3109):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3109):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.openPanel(PhoneWindow.java:655)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3109):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.openPanel(PhoneWindow.java:523)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3109):  at android.app.Activity.openOptionsMenu(Activity.java:2819)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3109):  at com.google.glass.myapp.MenuActivity.onResume(MenuActivity.java:44)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3109):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1187)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3109):  at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5183)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3109):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2732)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3109):  ... 12 more
W/ActivityManager(  439):   Force finishing activity com.google.glass.myapp/.MenuActivity
```

What's going on here? Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your onResume method. Try calling the super method first.

```
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        openOptionsMenu();
    }
```

instead of

```
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        openOptionsMenu();
        super.onResume();
    }
```